# Asp.net Core's POST method converting DateTime.Now to Min Date on model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, mstest, model-binding

i have a simple integration test.

```
        [TestMethod]
    public async Task INT_GetSomething_Sucess()
    {
        //Arrange
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        BidMonthDetails returnedObj;
        //Act
        try
        {
            string request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);
            response = await TestClient.PostAsync("/api/Trade/GetSomething", new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            returnedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }


        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        Assert.IsNotNull(returnedObj);


    }
```

this test the function called GetSomething in Trade controller

```
     [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> GetSomething(DateTime date)
    {
```

at this point the "date" is just the min date. i am expecting it to be Today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `DateTime` parameters are assumed to come from the query string. Since you don't have a `date` query string parameter, it is defaulting to the default value for `DateTime` which is `DateTime.Min`

To solve this you have a couple of options:

1) Decorate the parameter with the FromBody attribute:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> GetSomething([FromBody]DateTime date)
```

2) Put the value in the query string rather than the body:

```
response = await TestClient.PostAsync($"/api/Trade/GetSomething?date={DateTime.UtcNow}"...
```